# How to grant permissions / set role with ddl_command_start event trigger without explicit sql execution?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql, database-indexes

I encountered an issue while resetting the table owner whenever an index is created on table in psql. Am doing this programatically by defining **ddl_command_start**.

**Flow of events:**

1. On /create api execution, backend creates a table using role table_role and resets the owner to superuser/admin
2. On /createIndex api execution ,backend  tries to create index using role table_role , in doing so it cannot execute ddl_command_start as table_role is not the owner of created table in step1.

Is there a way to grant temporary access to the created table as owner in second step ? ( without executing an explicit sql from code )

Is it possible to invoke db function or other means to reset the role before permission check happens on a table ?

Please let me know your comments. Thank you.

```
permForIndexEndFunc := `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION internal.trg_create_index_set_owner()
                    RETURNS event_trigger
                    LANGUAGE plpgsql
                    SECURITY DEFINER
                    AS $$
                    DECLARE
                    obj record;
                    tablename text;
                    BEGIN
                    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag='CREATE INDEX' LOOP
                    tablename := substring(obj.object_identity from 1 for 10);
                    EXECUTE format('SET ROLE %s','admin');
                    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO table_role', tablename);
                    END LOOP;
                    END;
                    $$;`

    _, err = db.Exec(permForIndexEndFunc)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    permForIndexEndTrigger := `CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_index_set_owner
                    ON ddl_command_start
                    WHEN tag IN ('CREATE INDEX')
                    EXECUTE PROCEDURE internal.trg_create_index_set_owner();`
    _, err = db.Exec(permForIndexEndTrigger)
    if err != nil {
    return err 
    }
```

Basically my app creates generic ingestion db schemas based on client configuration (either through grpc / rest api calls),so customer would send the schema in the form of json & it creates the identical db schema in backend , then onwords customer sends data in the pre-defined json format.So basically when schema is created on db event triggers maintain the rbac of so and so schema,tables.Schema,table creation itself happens by assuming creation only role by resetting owner to superuser using event trigger, so by the time index creation owner of table has been reset & fail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the superuser/admin that owns the table from step 1 “user a”.

Then, for `table_role` to be allowed to create an index on the table, it must be a member of `a`. So you have to grant role membership temporarily:

```
BEGIN;
GRANT a TO table_role;
CREATE INDEX ...;
REVOKE a FROM table_role;
COMMIT;
```

Now if `a` is really a superuser, then of course `table_role` is not allowed to do that unless it is also a superuser (but in that case, the problem wouldn't exist, because superusers are allowed to do anything).

So make sure that `a` is no superuser. Then `table_role` needs to have `CREATEUSER` to be allowed to do tha above.

Comment: thank you @[Laurenz Albe], a quick question ,  is it possible to do this at trigger level / db level instead of doing it in code . I mean currently am doing db.Exec("Create Index") where db is session object instantiated with table_role , my intention was to avoid this.

Comment: I see. Sore, you could grant membership on `ddl_command_start` and revoke it on `ddl_command_end`, but why not grant the membership right away? This seems very complicated, but you are not telling us enough about the underlying idea and concept to give better advice. I feel that there is a better way than all this.

Comment: @Laurez Albe basically my app creates generic ingestion db schemas based on client configuration (either through grpc / rest api calls),so customer would send the schema in the form of json & I create the identical db schema in backend , then onwords customer sends data in the pre-defined json format.So basically when schema is created on db event triggers maintain the rbac of so and so schema,tables.Schema,table creation itself happens by assuming creation only role by resetting owner to superuser using event trigger, so by the time index creation owner of table has been reset & fails .

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add this information, making it easier to read. It would also be glad if you could explain all terms that are not database related (you didn't tag anything not database related, so expect only database people to read this), like "rbac". Please split in paragraphs and short sentences.

Comment: thank you , i mean role based access control at db level using event triggers